# Crashes during CoreData fetching on serial queue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, thread-safety

I went through many discutions and subjects about CoreData, but I keep getting the same problem.

Here's the context : I have an application which have to do several access to CoreData. I decided, for simplifying, to declare a **serial** thread specifically for access (queue.sync for fetching, queue.async for saving). I have a structure that is nested three times, and for recreating the entire structure, I fetch subSubObject, then SubObject and finally Object

But **sometimes** (like 1/5000 recreation of "Object") CoreData crash on fetching results, with no stack trace, with no crash log, only a
**EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1)**

Objects are not in cause, and the crash is weird because all access are done in the **same thread** which is a **serial thread**

If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful !

Here's the structure of the code :

```cs
private let delegate:AppDelegate
private let context:NSManagedObjectContext
private let queue:DispatchQueue

override init() {
    self.delegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    self.context = self.delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    self.queue = DispatchQueue(label: "aLabel", qos: DispatchQoS.utility)
    super.init()
}


(...)

public func loadObject(withID ID: Int)->Object? {

    var object:Object? = nil

    self.queue.sync {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Name")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", NSNumber(value: ID))

        do {
            var data:[NSManagedObject]

            // CRASH HERE ########################
            try data = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            // ###################################

            if (data.first != nil) {
                let subObjects:[Object] = loadSubObjects(forID: ID)
                // Task creating "object"
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("CoreData : \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    return object
}

private func loadSubObjects(forID ID: Int)->[Object] {

    var objects:[Object] = nil

    self.queue.sync {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Name")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", NSNumber(value: ID))

        do {
            var data:[NSManagedObject]

            // OR HERE ###########################
            try data = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            // ###################################

            if (data.first != nil) {
                let subSubObjects:[Object] = loadSubObjects(forID: ID)
                // Task creating "objects"
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("CoreData : \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    return objects
}

(etc...)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to init ManagedObjectContext on the right queue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988409/how-to-init-managedobjectcontext-on-the-right-queue)

Comment: Check out my answer in the duplicate . You should not use custom threads for Core Data. You can add this to your project to know when you are violating the threads in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391838/making-com-apple-coredata-concurrencydebug-1-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** get rid of your queue, replace it with an operation queue.  Run fetches on the main thread with `viewContext` do writing in one synchronous way.

There are two issues.  First is that managedObjectContexts are not thread safe.  You cannot access a context (neither for reading or for writing) except from the single thread that it is setup to work with.  The second issue is that you shouldn't be doing multiple writing to core-data at the same time. Simultaneous writes can lead to conflicts and loss of data.

The crash is cause by accessing `viewContext` from a thread that is not the main thread.  The fact that there is a queue ensuring that nothing else is accessing core data at the same time doesn't fix it.  When core-data thread safety is violated core-data can fail **at any time** and **in any way**.  That means that it may crash with hard to diagnose crash reports even at points in the code where you are on the correct thread.

You have the right idea that core-data needs a queue to work well when saving data, but your implementation is flawed. A queue for core-data will prevent write conflicts caused by writing conflicting properties to an entity at the same time from different context. Using `NSPersistentContainer` this is easy to set up.

In your core-data manager create a NSOperationQueue

```
let  persistentContainerQueue : OperationQueue = {
    let queue = OperationQueue.init();
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
    return queue;
}()
```

And do all writing using this queue:

```
func enqueueCoreDataBlock(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Swift.Void){
    persistentContainerQueue.addOperation {
        let context = self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext();
        context.performAndWait {
            block(context)
            do{
                try context.save();
            } catch{
                //log error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For writing use `enqueueCoreDataBlock:` which will give you a context to use and will execute every block inside the queue so you don't get write conflicts.  Make sure that no managedObject leave this block - they are attached to the context which will be destroyed at the end of the block. Also you can't pass managedObjects into this block - if you want to change a `viewContext` object you have to use the `objectID` and fetch in the background context. In order for the changes to be seen on the `viewContext` you have to add to your core-data setup `persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`

For reading you should use the `viewContext` from the main thread.  As you are generally reading in order to display information to the user you aren't gaining anything by having a different thread.  The main thread would have to wait for the information in any event so it is faster just the run the fetch on the main thread.  Never write on the `viewContext`.  The `viewContext` does not use the operation queue so writing on it can create write conflicts. Likewise you should treat any other contexts that you create (with `newBackgroundContext` or with `performBackgroundTask`) as readonly because they will also be outside of the writing queue.

At first I thought that  `NSPersistentContainer`'s `performBackgroundTask` had an internal queue, and initial testing supported that. After more testing I saw that it could also lead to merge conflicts.

Comment: Very useful, a big thanks ! You should write a tutorial because all I found didn't mentions the differences between 'viewContext' and 'persistantContainer'. I heard about the 'thread-safe' issue, but now it's clear !

Now I have several issues due to the update, I mark the post as "Answered" anyway :)

Ps: So, update should be done in "performBackgroundTask", right ?

(Ps2: sorry for English, French developper here x) )

Comment: All write should be done using `performBackgroundTask`

Comment: @JonRose big fetches will cause the ui to freeze no?

Comment: If you have a ViewController that is displaying a lot of data from the database you don't really have much else to do during that time except wait.  If your fetch is taking less than 100 milliseconds that is OK. True you are blocking the UI but less than 100 ms is ok.  If it is taking longer than that then your fetch is inefficient and that should be fixed.  I have never had a situation where a fetch takes a long time and could not fixed but making it more efficient.

Comment: Jon Rose, I think cannot understand clearly. Do I need to call enqueueCoreDataBlock inside performBackgroundTask? Or I have to make NSManagedObjects changed inside performBackgroundTask? Can you please show an example of how to call enqueueCoreDataBlock with performBackgroundTask?

Comment: @bodich Just use enqueueCoreDataBlock - it calls performBackgroundTask and passes the context along. Something like CoreDataManager.shared.enqueueCoreDataBlock { context in /// use the context to do stuff and don't reference it outside of this block }
(some of the confusion in the comment above was from a previous version of the answer which didn't have a separate operation queue)

Comment: @JonRose Sorry I just don't see enqueueCoreDataBlock calling performBackgroundTask in example. Or you mean when you call newBackgroundContext() it automatically calls performBackgroundTask somewhere behind?

Comment: yes, sorry for not being clear. newBackgroundContext() and perform() is doing the same thing that performBackgroundTask is doing.

Comment: @JonRose Oh got it, so I don't need to use performBackgroundTask directly, only the code from example is complete and enough. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: @JonRose Can you please tell me one more thing? Can I fetch item from persistantContainer.viewContext, but modify/save it inside enqueueCoreDataBlock? I mean I fetch items, then I edit item, at the same time it can be modified remotely by CloudKit...

Comment: If you need to modify objects you must fetch them inside a enqueueCoreDataBlock with the given context. Do not use any other context. Do not edit viewContext objects. Do not use any managed object inside a enqueueCoreDataBlock that was not created inside the block.

Comment: @JonRose Can you recommend a solution in this case please? I fetch objects from Core Data, then fetch records from CloudKit, and in callback I have to modify fetched Core Data records and save context. Callback can return in few seconds and goes from another thread, or can not return... But I need to continue working with Core Data while CloudKit is fetching...

Comment: @JonRose Btw, all my fetched data has "data: <fault>" when fetching inside enqueueCoreDataBlock and send it to the main thread. It's fine inside enqueueCoreDataBlock but all become "data: <fault>" once sent outside...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218459/discussion-between-jon-rose-and-bodich).